# How can a HID device be connected, but not paired?

Tags: bluetooth

I am using `bluetoothctl` to connect a Bluetooth HID device to a Raspberry Pi. I can get it to work, but I am quite confused by the terminology, and how it all fits together.

- When running `scan on`, and having the HID device in pairing mode, it finds the device and it also shows up in the `devices` list.
- As long as it is in the `devices` list, I can use `info MAC` to get some info on it. By default, it says `Paired: no`, `Trusted: no`, `Connected: no`.
- I have to do both `trust MAC` and `pair MAC` to have the device work as HID.

Then, trying to keep it all working, I found this (IMHO) weird behaviour: when I switch off the device, I see `Connected` go to `no`, but `Paired` as well! `Trusted` stays on `yes`. When reconnecting, everything says `yes`, except for `Paired`. The device does not work as HID, until I `pair MAC` it.

Finally, when I `untrust` the device, it is removed from the `devices` list, and I need to go through a (lengthy) scan to get it trusted/paired/connected again.

My questions now are:

- How can a HID device be connected, when it is not paired?
- How can a HID device be connected, yet not work as HID (i.e., typing does not work) ?
- What is the difference between pairing and trusting a device?

Comment: It may not be using the standard terminology. It makes sense when I use these meanings: "Connected = Device is visible" & "trusted = remember this known Device" & "Paired = User has exchanged Passkey & Device is ready to use" : Initially all visible Devices are shown C=YES T=NO P=NO : When we Pair a Device & remember it C=Y,T=Y,P=Y : When Device is off, C=N,T=Y,P=N : When it is turned on, C=Y,T=Y,P=N when it is not being automatically Paired (bug in RPI) : When I change "trusted" to "remember" & "connected" to "visible", it makes sense. The RPI bug makes it necessary to unremember & reconnect!

Comment: @Prem Is this a known bug, and if so do you perhaps know some documentation about it (like a bug report or so?)

Comment: Somewhat related (1) https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/8h4cqz/rpi_3b_wont_autopair_trusted_device/ (2) https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=324225 [[ You could Post this on the RPI forums to check on latest updates to such issues ]]